# Set a select option after page redirection

Tags: jquery

I've a form in one HTML page that contains a select (values are in French)

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Secteur *</label>
     <select id="sector" name ="sector" class="form-control placeholder" required="required" onClick="document.getElementById('bouton').disabled = false"> 
         <option value="" selected disabled>Veuillez choisir un secteur d'activité</option>
         <option value="BTP">BTP</option>
         <option value="Second œuvre">Second œuvre</option>
         <option value="Maintenance et tertiaire">Maintenance et tertiaire</option>
         <option value="Transport et logistique">Transport et logistique</option>
         <option value="Pharmacie">Pharmacie</option>
         <option value="Transport en commun">Transport en commun</option>
         <option value="Transport et manutention">Transport et manutention</option>
         <option value="Coiffure et beauté">Coiffure et beauté</option>
         <option value="Evénementiel">Evénementiel</option>
         <option value ="Agent d'exploitation parking">Agent d'exploitation parking</option>
         <option value="Autre">Autre</option>
       </select>
 </div>
```

And I've another page that contains multiples activity sectors. What I'd like to do is :
if user click on a button that is related to the sector "BTP", it redirects him to the form on the other page, with the select option "BTP" already displayed.

A few screens to explain it properly :

Here, on agence.html :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/He16w.png

If I click on "Postuler" button, I'd like to be redirected to the page candidat.html and get "BTP" selected in the dropdown

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqTzF.png

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does the button pass $_GET information?

Comment: How have you tried to solve the problem? Please show us your code.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by *select option "BTP" already displayed*. Is it a checkbox you want to be checked ?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. What I tried to do is using jQuery to redirect to the form page after the button has been clicked and then set the select option to the appropriate one.

Comment: It is a dropdown menu, not a checkbox.

Comment: I've edited with a few screens to explain what I want

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with cookies. I used the very popular plugin [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for this.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Read the cookie and if it's defined select the option
    var option = $.cookie('option');
    if(option){
        $('#sector option[value="'+ option +'"]').attr("selected", "selected");
    }

    // Change '#postuler-button' to the correct selector
    $('#postuler-button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.cookie('option', 'BTP');
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

Comment: Work for you @Caedes?

Comment: I tried several times but I can't get it work. Thank you for your help @lmgonzalves, but I gave up on that idea, seems way too hard to implement for a little extra user experience. Unless someone has another idea.